# GMSMarker saving userData initially, but (null) when retrieved

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, parse-platform, google-maps-sdk-ios

**UPDATE**

The code works when you store the point and then tap it. The problem is, when I close the app and restart it, the data is gone...its only null after restarting the app. Any ideas?

I am trying to store userData in a GMSMarker and then retrieve it for a comparison later. This is my code for storing:

```
int r = arc4random_uniform(99999999);

matched = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:NO];

PFGeoPoint *point = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:mapView_.myLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:mapView_.myLocation.coordinate.longitude];

PFObject *pointstore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"MapPoints"];
pointstore[@"title"] = [userdefaults objectForKey:@"pfuser"];
pointstore[@"location"] = point;
pointstore[@"count"] = stored;
pointstore[@"matched"] = matched;
pointstore[@"marker_id"] = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInteger:r]];

[pointstore saveEventually:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Error");
    }
    else {
         GMSMarker *marker3 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
         marker3.position = mapView_.myLocation.coordinate;
         marker3.title = [userdefaults objectForKey:@"pfuser"];
         marker3.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];
         marker3.userData = @{@"marker_id":[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", r]};
         NSLog(@"****markerdata****");
         NSLog([[NSNumber numberWithInt:r] description]);
         marker3.map = mapView_;
         NSLog(@"****markerdataafter****");
         NSLog([marker3.userData description]);
     }
}];
```

The last log message `markerdataafter` is correct, which I thought means that the data had been successfully stored.

However when I retrieve it, with this code:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapInfoWindowOfMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {

    ...

    NSLog(@"****gettingtapped****");
    NSLog([marker.userData objectForKey:@"marker_id"]);

    ...
```

It is returned as `(null)`, so its not finding what I stored. This one has been baffling me for hours...any help is appreciated. Im also wondering if there is a better way to handle making the `marker_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I made the stupid mistake of not assigning the `userData` to the markers when they are initialized.